# why contacts length could be 0 when collision2D happens in Unity3D?

Tags: unity, collision-detection

I made a ball with `RigidBody2d` and `CircleCollider2D` to collide with other balls with the same component, and I simply use the following snippet to check the contacts of the collision:

```
public void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
        if(collision.contacts.Length == 0)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning(" collision contacts length is 0 ");
            return;
        }
        // futher more code to deal with situation when contacts exists
}
```

And I found sometimes the collision could happen without contacts I mean the `contacts` array could contain 0 points.

Why does that happen?

Cause it's very important for me to find the normal direction of the collision, but without a contact-point, I could find that.

[image]

Comment: Unity suggests to use `Collision2D.GetContacts` instead of `Collision2D.contacts`. Also on the page about `Collision` it says "you can always be sure that contacts has at least one element." but it does not say the same in `Collision2D` class, so maybe on 2D you can expect sometimes to not have any contacts ?

Comment: I made some research, and apparently this is a strange behaviour that goes on since more than 5 years. Have you tried to check it the `contacts` array shows at least one point one frame next from triggering `OnCollisionsEnter2D`? I know it beats the purpose, but that could something strange going in inside the Unity engine.